# Trivial elements in $T(a,b,c)$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Consider the group $T(a,b,2)=<x,y|x^a, y^b, (xy)^2>$ and assume none of $a$ or $b$ is equal to $2$. How can one list all the trivial words (say up to length $11$ and apart from $(xy)^{2n})$) in this group.

Comment: This depends a great deal on $a$ and $b$. If $a=b=3$ for example, then the group is just $A_4$ of order $12$, and there is a huge number trivial words of length up to $11$. But if $a$ and $b$ are both bigger than $11$, then the  only trivial words are the conjugates of powers of $(xy)^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: thanks for the comments. All the words are cyclically reduced. So that if $a,b>11$, the trivial words are $(xy)^{2n}$ (which is the case I removed in my question). I am very interested in how to show that they are the only ones though.

Comment: In general, if $1/a+1/b+1/c<1$ the a word represents the trivial word if and only if the word contains more than half of a cyclic shift of a relator or the inverse of a relator.

Comment: @user1729: thanks. i need sketch of idea of proof and/or references.

Comment: @user1729: The condition you give is necessary but not sufficient. The full sufficient condition for this case is Dehn's Algorithm.

Comment: @Lew Yes, sorry, what I wrote was supposed to be Dehn's algorithm. I meant "if a word represents the trivial word then it contains a Dehn subword".

Answer (score 2):

In the case that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} < 1$, which for your situation $c=2$ amounts to $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{2}$, [Dehn's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory#Dehn.27s_algorithm) is a computational algorithm for checking whether a word represents the identity element in this groups.

To justify Dehn's algorithm we need two facts.

First, $T(a,b,2)$ is a word hyperbolic group when the above inequality holds; that's a consequence of applying the Poincare polygon theorem to a hyperbolic polygon with angles $\pi/a$, $\pi/b$, $\pi/2$, reflecting that polygon across a side and taking the union to get a fundamental domain for an action of $T(a,b,2)$ on the hyperbolic plane.

Second, every word hyperbolic group has some finite set $R$ of defining relations that satisfies Dehn's algorithm; see the book by Epstein, Cannon, Holt, Levy, Paterson, Thurston.

So the conclusion is that Dehn's algorithm for some defining relators $R$ applies to your group $T(a,b,2)$ with respect to some presentation, and this is what allows you to list out all trivial words. Now, I am a little unsure whether your exact presentation is a Dehn's algorithm presentation for $T(a,b,2)$ when the inequality above holds; although I am 95% sure that it is and I think you can verify this by carrying out Dehn's original proof of his algorithm for the usual presentations of surface groups.

The statement of Dehn's algorithm, and the answer to your question assuming you have the correct defining relators $R$, is as follows. For any word $w$ in $x,y,z$ and their inverses, the word $w$ represents the identity element of the group if and only if iteration of the following process eventually reduces $w$ to the empty word: if $r \in R$ is one of the defining relators or their inverses or the cyclic permutations thereof, if $r=uv$ where $Length(u) > \frac{1}{2} Length(r)$, and if $w$ has a subword $u$, rewrite $w$ by replacing the $u$ subword with $v$.

Comment: thanks for the answer as that leaves me with just a few (five) cases to consider. I would like a (good/basic) reference for Poincare polygon theorem and also point out a typo in your answer: $Length(v)$ should be $Length(r)$.

Comment: @HeskyCee: Ratcliffe's book is good for detailed basic information on hyperbolic manifolds, including the Poincare polyhedron theorem in any dimension. But it might be better on first reading to stick with the 2-d version, the Poincare polygon theorem, and for that I would recommend Maskit's paper in Adv. Math. 7, 219--230 (1971), "On Poincare's theorem for fundamental polygons". And the finitely many remaining cases are covered by the Euclidean version of Poincare's polygon theorem.

Comment: Thr presentation $\langle x, y; x^a, y^b, (xy)^c\rangle$ has word problem soluble by Dehn's algorithm. I think Fine and Rosenberger's book on algebraic generalisations of discrete groups is a reference. I'll double-check tomorrow.

Comment: And back to my original question and maybe I did not state it quite well. I am not really trying to prove that a word is trivial but rather the form of it (as in Derek's comment above) i.e something like given that a word of free product length $7$ is trivial, then it has the form $x^3y...y^2$ (say).

Comment: @HeskyCee This is essentially what Dehn's algorithm gives you! If a word %W% represents the trivial word then $W$ contains such a subword (as does every cyclic shift of $W$).

Comment: oh yeah! I see why now.